# script, filename = argv of Python in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, python-3.x, powershell

I am reading "learn python the hard way". There are some lines say

`from sys import argv`

`script, filename = argv`

I can get these lines to work in notepad++ and PowerShell by typing 
`python myfile.py myfile.txt`. But I don't know how to let Eclipse run these lines. In Eclipse, there is no where that I can type "myfile.txt", it will just run through all the lines.

I am using python 2 for the PowerShell and python 3 for eclipse

Comment: Have a look at this link. Should get you started with python development on eclipse - https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs188/fa06/eclipse.html

Comment: Not sure that the PowerShell tag is needed here. You should be able to invoke the same from **cmd.exe** (assuming python is in the path)?

Comment: You need to install `PyDev` and then you can create a Python project to begin with.